# how to setup value of select using knockout and typescript on async call

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, typescript

my view model code looks like this.

```
export class viewModel {
providers: KnockoutObservableArray<PatientProviderModule.ProviderList>;
selectedProvider: KnockoutObservable<PatientProviderModule.ProviderList>;

billingService: BillingService;


patientProviderInfo: KnockoutObservableArray<PatientProviderModel>;
constructor(selectedProvider: number) {
    this.providers = ko.observableArray<PatientProviderModule.ProviderList>();
    this.billingService = new BillingService();
    this.patientProviderInfo = ko.observableArray<PatientProviderModel>();
    this.loadData();
    this.selectedProvider = "what should come here?";
}
loadData = () => {
    this.billingService.getPatientAndProviderInfo().then((data: PatientProviderModel) => {
        this.providers.pushAll(data.ProviderList);
        this.selectedProvider = ko.observable(this.providers()[2]);
    });
}
```

}

and on html side it is bound like this.

```
    <select data-bind="options: providers, value: selectedProvider,  optionsCaption: '', optionsValue: 'prov_id', optionsText: 'FullName'"></select>
```

loadData function populates the drop down data in 'providers'. after that is being populated i am trying to select last option in that drop down. but it doesn not select any option. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting selectedProvider to an observable asynchronously in loadData. What this means is that field is not yet an Observable at the time the UI is bound to your model, and therefore does not know to look for change events. You should instantiate selectedProvider to a new observable immediately in the constructor and then update the existing observable's value in loadData.

setting up constructor

```
 this.selectedProvider = ko.observable();
```

and load function

```
this.selectedProvider(this.providers()[2].prov_id);
```

worked!!

Comment: kindly review the update i actually wanted  value: selectedProvider i wanted a selection on load. but i am trying to work out what you said.

Comment: in constructor i have         this.selectedProvider = ko.observable<number>();

in loadData i am doing     this.selectedProvider = ko.observable(2);

Comment: In constructor use `this.selectedProvider = ko.observable();` and in loadData use `this.selectedProvider(this.providers()[2]);`

Comment: that my first line in constructor  and globally its like     selectedProvider: KnockoutObservable<{}>;               but still not working. same stuff works for static array. i.e. hard coded array.

Comment: in "then" of my promise i have 
........................
            this.providers(data.ProviderList);
            this.selectedProvider(this.providers()[2]);
and constructor like u said. but still no luck.

Comment: it was     this.selectedProvider(this.providers()[2].prov_id);


:)